# transform() must be an instance of App\DigitalCase

Tags: php, laravel

```
public function index(Request $request) {
    if ($request->has('show_type') && $request->show_type == 'deleted') {
        $digital_cases = DigitalCase::onlyTrashed()->get();
    } else {
        $digital_cases = DB::table('digital_cases');
        if ($request->has('caseName')) {
            $digital_cases = $digital_cases->where('name', 'LIKE', $request->caseName . '%');
            if ($request->has('addedBy')) {
                $addedBy = $request->addedBy;
                $digital_cases = $digital_cases->whereIn('added_by', function ($query) use ($addedBy) {
                    $query->select('id')->from('assistants')->where('firstname', 'LIKE', $addedBy . '%');
                });
            }
        } else if ($request->has('addedBy')) {
            $addedBy = $request->addedBy;
            $digital_cases = $digital_cases->whereIn('added_by', function ($query) use ($addedBy) {
                $query->select('id')->from('assistants')->where('firstname', 'LIKE', $addedBy . '%');
            });
        }

        $digital_cases = $digital_cases->get();
    }

    $transformation = fractal()->transformWith(new DigitalCaseTransformer())->collection($digital_cases)->toArray();
    return response()->json($transformation, 200);
}
```

I really tired of asking questions. But i have last problem is; i couldnt convert digital_cases to DigitalCase Model instance.

I got an error :

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Transformers\DigitalCaseTransformer::transform() must be an instance of App\DigitalCase, instance of stdClass given, called in

If it work in IF condition everything is ok. But when it work in ELSE condition it returns an error. How can i convert digital_cases variable to instance of DigitalCase ?

Laravel 5.6

Comment: Why are you using `$digital_cases = DB::table('digital_cases');`? Are you just trying to start the query so you can append conditions to that?

Comment: @TimLewis how can i do? If i try DigitalCase::all(), it returns empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `$digital_cases = DB::table('digital_cases');` will not give you an instance (or Collection of) the `DigitalCase` Model. You need to use `DigitalCase`. To start a query that you can append conditional clauses to, begin with

```
$digital_cases = DigitalCase::query();
```

Then, continue appending clauses in the same way. When you pass a closure (`->get()`, etc), you'll end up with a Collection of `DigitalCase` Models (or a single `DigitalCase` if using `->first()`).

Answer (score 2):

You can really simplify and clean up the conditional queries using `when`:

```
DigitalCase::when($request->has('caseName'), function ($q) {
    return $q->where('name', 'LIKE', request()->caseName . '%');
})->when($request->has('addedBy'), function ($q) {
    return $q->whereIn('added_by', function ($query) {
        $query->select('id')->from('assistants')->where('firstname', 'LIKE', request()->addedBy . '%');
    });
}})->get();
```

That will yield the same result as all the `if () { .. } else if () { .. }`